# How are the tangential divergence and tangential Laplace operators defined in spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, differential-topology, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates, divergence-operator

Suppose that the 2D vector field
$$\boldsymbol{u} (x,y,z) = u_x (x,y,z) \hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_x + u_y (x,y,z) \hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_y$$
satisfies the property
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_\parallel \cdot \boldsymbol{u} = 0 \tag{1}
$$
with $\boldsymbol{\nabla}_\parallel$ representing the tangential gradient, expressed in the system of Cartesian coordinates by
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_\parallel = \hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_x \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
+ \hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_y \, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \, .
$$
Accordingly, Eq. (1) is written in Cartesian coordinates as
$$
\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y} = 0 \, .
$$

Now I would like to express Eq. (1) in spherical coordinates in terms of $u_r$, $u_\theta$, and $u_\phi$, which represent the radial, polar, and azimuthal components of the vector field $\boldsymbol{u}$ in the system of spherical coordinates (using a physicist's notation.)

From the expression of the usual divergence in spherical coordinates  we have ([Wikipedia][1])
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{u} = 
\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 u_r \right)
+ \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left( u_\theta \sin\theta \right)
+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial \phi} \, .
$$

What I was able to get using an example vector field that
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_\parallel \cdot \boldsymbol{u} = 
\frac{u_r}{r}
+ \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left( u_\theta \sin\theta \right)
+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial u_\phi}{\partial \phi} \, .
$$

> I have no idea why we get the first term $u_r/r$.

I would expect that the tangential divergence would only involve tangential contributions given that
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}_\parallel f = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \, \hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_\theta
+ \frac{1}{r \sin\theta} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \, 
\hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_\phi \, .
$$

Any clarification is highly appreciated. Thank you!

In addition, how the tangential Laplace operator
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla}^2_\parallel \boldsymbol{u} = 
\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right) u_x \, \hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_x
+
\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}
+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right) u_y \, \hat{\boldsymbol{e}}_y
$$
is defined in spherical coordinates?

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: In the first half of your question when only Cartesian coordinates are involved the variable $z$ is just a parameter we can ignore. Therefore I would think 2D polar coordinates $(r,\varphi)\leftrightarrow(x,y)$ reflect this better.

Comment: @KurtG. Since I will have to deal with a spherical geometry I need the expressions of the tangential div and tangential Laplacian in spherical coordinates.

Comment: Let me rephrase: your $\nabla_{\|}$ is unable to measure anything that has to do with $z\,.$ Any operator that takes more derivatives than just two cannot be a representation of $\nabla_{\|}$ in other coordinates. Imho: the right "spherical" system are cylindrical coordinates where $\partial_z$ is ignored. That's the same as 2D polar coordinates. Where does that problem originally come from and what makes you think you are have to deal with spherical geometry?

Comment: @KurtG. This arises in a fluid mechanical problem in which the flow field induced by a point force acting tangent to an interface has such a form. Now suppose that you have a translating sphere bisected by this surface. I am trying to build a sort of solution that satisfies the no-slip boundary condition at the surface of the sphere. Perhaps it would be much better to use polar coordinates here as you mentioned. Thanks. I will have a look.